# ¿Qué quiere decir "Dengue" en "Raid: Mata al mosquito del Dengue"?

Tags: méxico

Supongo que podría ser que significa "caca" porque la palabra suena como "Dung" pero no corresponde a ningún definición [del RAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=CBYWJWJ%7CCBZ484R).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sin duda hace referencia al [**dengue**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dengue), una enfermedad cuyo vector es una de las especies de mosquito ([*Aedes aegypti*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aedes_aegypti)).  Nota que el nombre común de ese mosquito es el mosquito *de la fiebre amarilla*, el cual indica su estatus como portador principal de aquella enfermedad, pero también lo es para el dengue.  En Méjico, la fiebra amarilla ya se desconoce hoy, pero el dengue está presente en muchas partes, con lo cual hace más sentido darle a *Aedes aegypti* el nombre común de *mosquito del dengue*.